# How the date can be formatted in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, java-7

There is simpleDateFormat available in java,similarly is there any way to format the date in JavaScript

What is the best equivalent way to perform date formats in JavaScript.

Comment: try http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: Why not try to do it yourself? that's always fun.

Answer (score 0):

I think In javascript we don't have straight forward functions to get dateformats, to  get the exact format you need to call differnt functions on Date object(in javascript).

but in jqueryUI we have formatDate().

var d = new Date(2016, 0, 30)  // 30 Jan 2016

alert( formatDate(d) )  // '30.01.16'